# How to pass Array to SOAP API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, soap

I need to pass this array to SOAP API as a parameter. The back-end guy is new to building APIs (C#/.NET) and I have never implemented this kind of API before. There are 4-5 SO question related to this. But none of them were the solution as per my query.

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];

NSString *soapURL = @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/addRecord";
NSString *soapBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<addRecord xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                      "<id>%@</id>"
                      "<title>%@</title>"
                      "<record>%@</record>"
                      "</addRecord> \n” ,@“1”,@“abc", arr ];

NSLog(@"%@",soapBody);
```

Error:

> value in string The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'addRecord'. End element 'record' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found text '(
>       1,
>       2
>   )'.

One thing I came to know that I cannot pass array directly in to `soapBody`. What what is the alternative?

The API is working fine at the back-end.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383522 - you need to look at your schema to make sure that the `record` element is defined correctly and then you will need to use a loop to unpack your array and build the correct xml using string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue with this code:

```
NSString *soapBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"< addRecord xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" xmlns:arr=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\" > \n"
                          "<ID>1</ID>\n"
                          "<title>ABC</title>\n"
                          "<record>\n"];

    for (int i=0; i<arrRecord.count; i++) {
        soapBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <arr:int>%@</arr:int>\n",soapBody,arrRecord[i]];
    }

    soapBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ </record></addRecord> \n",soapBody];
```

I needed to define "arr" in the parent node and type of element(int) in the record array.

Answer (score 1):

some comments:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
```

please write instead the modern form:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"1",@"2"];
```

Also, your question is filled with wrong types of quotes (`“1”`). Make sure to use the regular quotes, i.e. `"`.

When you use "stringWithFormat" with %@ and provide an array, you must understand what you are getting there. let's try:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"1",@"2"];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", arr];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

The result is:

```
<(
    1,
    2
)>
```

It means that between your `<record>` and `</record>` you inserted two numbers separated by a comma and surrounded by parentheses, plus some `\n`.

Is this what your server is expecting?

So I am not solving your problem, but you must format your string the right way and verify it using your NSLog command. Hoping it is helping.

EDIT

If for example you need to provide the values of the array within `<value>...</value>` than you can do this:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"1", @"2"];
NSMutableString *mStr = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *value in arr) {
    [mStr appendFormat:@"<value>%@</value>", value];
}
NSLog(@"<record>%@</record>", mStr);
```

And the result will be

```
<record><value>1</value><value>2</value></record>
```

Comment: You are right about the about things you have mentioned. And Server expects it to be an array. So I am passing the array, but it is not in correct format.
But can we pass array objects without key, this is the question now?

Comment: For SOAP you probably need to provided a sequence of values surrounded by `<tag>`...`</tag>`. So iterate over your array and construct an NSMutableString with the correct format of the required data, and give that string instead of your arr

Comment: An example or reference link will helpful.

Comment: Did my answer help? if yes please accept. If not please explain where you are stuck

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. You could be nice for my efforts and give me a +1. BTW your code is not efficient. you create new `NSString` for the same variable several times. Better to use `NSMutableString` like I did in my example